# How to save the preferences with a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, itemlistener

I'm new to Java and I am trying to save the preferences on an option window. I am creating maps of the game with JLabel matrices. I have 3 maps, and the user will select them with a Combo box and select rounds (1 rounds,3 rounds or 5 rounds) for the game and I need to save those options being selected by the user.

This is the method for the combobox, now the this is that I don't know how to added to the botton so that it save the settings, so when the user click on New Game it will open the options that was being selected before. I'm using Menu Items. Where tab is the variable for my class Tablero.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
   int selectedIndex = combobox.getSelectedIndex();
             switch(selectedIndex){
                    case 0: //small map

                          tab.matrizpeque();
                          tab.llmatrizpeque(5,8);
                                             break;
                   case 1: //med map

                          tab.matrizmed();
                          tab.llmatrizmed(8,12);
                                             break;
                  case 2: //big map

                          tab.matrizbig();
                          tab.llmatrizbig(10,15);
                                             break;
                        }    

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Java preferences api is the standard way to do this
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need an example becuase I don't quite understand the preferences api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql to persist the data, that's the easier way. Another good option is an xml file. do a search for persistence with xml.